# How to instantiate a class X in a sub-method of X with the same parameters in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, initialization, instance-variables

I have a the following exemplary code:

```
class X:
 def __init__(self, value):
  self.value = value

 def method_a(self):
  ...
```

I now want to **instantiate a new object of *X* within *method_a***, re-using `value`, i.e.

```
def method_a(self):
 x = X(value = self.value)
```

Now, imagine I have **several** **parameters** to set in the constructor of `X`. Is there a "pythonic" way to re-set/copy all the parameters at once? Something like:

```
def method_a(self):
 x = X(self)
```

The latter doesn't work ("_init__() missing 1 required positional argument"). I also couldn't find any solution to this problem case in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) module may be what you need:

#### Code

```
def method_a(self):
    return copy.copy(self)
```

#### Finer Control :

In various scenarios you may need to copy only some parameters, that can be done using [*unpacking of argument lists*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) combined with [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to manage longer lists to copy:

```
def method_a(self):
    attributes_to_copy = ('value1', 'value2')
    kwargs = {k: getattr(self, k) for k in attributes_to_copy}
    return type(self)(**kwargs)
```

#### Test code:

```
import copy

class X(object):
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2

    def method_a(self):
        return copy.copy(self)

    def method_b(self):
        attributes_to_copy = ('value1', 'value2')
        kwargs = {k: getattr(self, k) for k in attributes_to_copy}
        return type(self)(**kwargs)

x1 = X(1, 2)
x2 = x1.method_a()
x3 = x1.method_b()
assert x1.value1 == x2.value1
assert x1.value1 == x3.value1
```